# Gradle aggregation task

Tags: gradle

In my gradle scripts, I've built a task that runs a java process. This process depends on a target property. The task is defined by:

```groovy
task('bulk', type: JavaExec, dependsOn: 'classes', description : 'Bulk data import on a target (defined by -Ptarget=[event|member|...]]') {

//available imports
ext{
    event = relativePath('src/main/scripts/events.csv')
    member = relativePath('src/main/scripts/member.csv')
    membership = relativePath('src/main/scripts/membership.csv')
}

//check the target is set 
doFirst {
    if(!project.hasProperty('target')){

        println "\nUsage:"
        println "\tgradle bulk -Ptarget=[event|member|...]"
        println "where target is : "
        bulk.ext.each{ println it }

        throw new GradleException('Target argument required')
    } else {
        println "\nBulk import of  $target\n"
    }
}

main = 'org.yajug.users.bulkimport.BulkImport'
classpath = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
if(project.hasProperty('target')){
    bulk{
            args target
            args bulk.ext[target]
        debug false
        }
    }
}
```

And to run it:

```bash
gradle bulk -Ptarget=event
```

It's working fine, but know I have to run this process for different targets:

```bash
gradle bulk -Ptarget=event
gradle bulk -Ptarget=member
gradle bulk -Ptarget=membership
...
```

**How can I group all these calls into an other single task with the gradle's dependency model ?** (I know the list of targets)

**SOLUTION**

```groovy
task bulk;
['event','member','membership'].each {target ->
    task("bulk${target}", type: JavaExec, dependsOn: 'classes', description : "Bulk data import of ${target}s") {

        //available imports
        ext{
            event = relativePath('src/main/scripts/events.csv')
            member = relativePath('src/main/scripts/member.csv')
            membership = relativePath('src/main/scripts/membership.csv')
        }

        //check the target is set 
        doFirst {
            println "\nBulk import of  $target\n"
        }

        main = 'org.yajug.users.bulkimport.BulkImport'
        classpath = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
        args target
        args ext[target]
        debug false

    }
    bulk.dependsOn("bulk${target}")
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I group all these calls into an other single task with the gradle's dependency model ?

You can't, because a task (instance) will be executed at most once per build. Instead, the way to go is to declare multiple task instances. You could do this by putting the task declaration in a loop, putting it in a method and calling it multiple times, or by writing a task class and instantiating it multiple times. Then you'll add one other task that depends on all `bulk` tasks. Assuming the execution order between `bulk` tasks is irrelevant, that's it.

By adding a helper method or two, you can create a nice little API around this, to improve readability and allow reuse in other places.

Another way to tackle this is with a task *rule*. You can read more on task rules in the [Gradle User Guide](http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/userguide_single.html#N10ED4).

Answer (score 1):

What about creating a `-Ptarget=all`, and deal with that specific case in the build.gradle file. This could be done as:

```
['event','member','membership'].each { t ->
   task("bulk${t}", ...) {
     onlyIf project.hasProperty("target") && (project.getProperty("target").equals(t) || project.getProperty("target").equals("all"))
     args target
     args bulk.ext[target]
     debug false
   }
}
```