# Aggregate tasks in Gradle

Tags: groovy, gradle

I'm working on a gradle task that depends on other gradle tasks, i.e an aggregate task. The aggregate task required the other tasks to run in a certain linear order too.

Note: The other tasks must be able to run in isolation. The dependencies between the tasks ONLY makes sense when running the aggregate task.

My first attempt was to use someTask.execute(), but then I realized that this was not the Gradle way, i.e it is not a supported feature and that the internal API might change.

```
task aggregate() {

  doFirst {
    // Need to set properties required by other tasks
    project.ext.somePropRequiredByTask1 = propertyX + "-" propertyY
  } 

  doLast {
     task1.execute()
     task2.execute()
     task3.execute()
  }
}
```

After reading up on creating aggregate tasks, this is my current solution:

```
task aggregate() {
  // Only configure task if the task is exlicitly run
  if (gradle.startParamter.taskNames.contains("aggregate") {
    project.ext.somePropRequiredByTask1 = propertyX + "-" propertyY
    chainTaskDependencies([task1, task2, task3])   
  }
}

// Create a strict dependsOn dependency order for the tasks in the task list
def chainTaskDependencies(List<Task> tasks) {
  def taskNames = tasks.collect { it.name}
  println "Run tasks in this order: " taskNames.join " -> "

  def reversed = tasks.reverse()
  for (int i = 0; i< reversed.size() -1 ; i ++) {
    reversed[i].dependsOn(reversed[i+1])
  }
}
```

Is this the correct way to create an aggregate task dependency where the order between tasks is linear? How can it be improved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about just extracting shutdownVM, waitForVMShutdown and rollback to functions/closures that your tasks call ? Then you are free to compose them in any which way you choose.

I've found this to be the most flexible option in similar cases.

Answer (score 0):

As Gradle team member and Spock inventor Peter Neiderweiser puts it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14605252/gradle-aggregation-task):

> You can't, because a task (instance) will be executed at most once per build. Instead, the way to go is to declare multiple task instances. You could do this by putting the task declaration in a loop, putting it in a method and calling it multiple times, or by writing a task class and instantiating it multiple times. Then you'll add one other task that depends on all bulk tasks. Assuming the execution order between bulk tasks is irrelevant, that's it.

He also suggests using [task rules](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/userguide_single.html#N10F30) for this purpose.

The OP also posts the solution he or she devised, so you can look at that as well.

Comment: The thing is that the other tasks must be able to run in isolation. The dependencies between the tasks ONLY makes sense when running the aggregate task. Thanks for pointing this out, I will update my question to accomodate for this.

Comment: If I understand the other answer correctly, he suggests that you create tasks dynamically. I have to use already existing tasks that are used in other contexts as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
B.mustRunAfter(A)
```

means that if both A and B run then B must run after A. B can be run by itself no problems.

So:

```
task A
task B
task C
task aggregate(dependsOn(['A', 'B', 'C'])

C.mustRunAfter(B)
B.mustRunAfter(A)
```

Comment: How is this any different than my solution, other than the fact that you have hard coded the task dependencies globally? The dependencies between the tasks only makes sense in the context of running the aggregate task.

Comment: I don't actually see how your solution does what you want - unless you meant to have the call to chainTaskDependencies inside the if? In any case, I have not declared any dependencies between A, B and C; only between them and the aggregate. 'mustRunAfter' is not a dependency relationship, but an ordering - In fact Gradle is quite opinionated that dependencies should not be used for ordering. B.mustRunAfter(A) means that any time B and A are run together they must run in that order. If they are not run together then it has no effect.

Comment: I'm interested in your statement that 'The dependencies between the tasks only makes sense in the context of running the aggregate task'. I assume you are talking about ordering? It is true that B.mustRunAfter(A) means they will run in that order any time they run together, not just when triggered by that particular aggregate. Can you explain why that won't work for you - perhaps with an example?

Comment: Alright, so my specific use case is this (simplified): task A = shutdown VM, task B = wait for VM to shutdown, task C = rollback to initial snapshot. Having a dependency between task A and B makes sense for the aggregate task of shutdown + wait + rollback, but in general I do not want a dependency between shutting down and waiting for the actual shutdown to finish. Sometimes this makes sense, sometimes it does not.

Comment: Sorry, the chainTaskDependencies() should be inside the if as you pointed out, I fixed my example.

Comment: Maybe I'm being dense but I cant imagine a situation where I would run BOTH shutdown and wait together and not want them to be in that order?